# Have any other real people appeared in The Good Place?

Tags: the-good-place

Early in the final episode of The Good Place Chidi is leading a philosophy discussion and a disagreement emerges on the interpretation of a particular sentence in a book by the philosopher Todd May.

Chidi quotes the sentence as "mortality offers meaning to our lives" but an audience member chips in saying that the sentence actually reads "mortality offers meaning to the events of our lives". Eleanor responds that Chidi should know what he is talking about as he has been teaching philosophy for aeons. The audience member disagrees saying he *wrote* the sentence.

The audience member **is** Todd May (ie not an actor *playing* Todd May).

Are there any other examples where real people playing themselves appear in the show?

Comment: Why do you ignore the presence of Pamela Hieronymi in the finale? https://slate.com/culture/2020/02/the-good-place-finale-ending-explained-philosopher-cameos-analysis.html

Comment: Because there is no indication as to who she is playing?

Comment: @BCdotWEB I didn't ignore anyone: I asked a question so those who do recognise people can put them in an answer. I happened to recognise May from a picture on the back of one of his books purely by accident. Hence the question to see if there are other examples.

Comment: It's a real shame they couldn't get Blake Bortles to do a cameo.

Comment: @Paulie_D she is referenced by name as Dr Hieronymi

Answer (score 7):

**Timothy Olyphant in Season 4, Episode 10**

[image]

---

**Nick Offerman in Series Finale** - Possibly<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* - It's not clear if he's playing himself or his character from *Parks & Recreation* but since the scene involves woodworking and Offerman is a well-known woodworker it's *likely* it was meanto be himself.</sup>

[image]

Comment: Ron Swanson is also a highly skilled woodworker though!

Comment: There was a few cameos of ethics experts.